# System always start with "System program problem detected" dialog

Tags: apport

[image]

Hello,

I'm getting this error every time when I boot my computer. My Ubuntu installation is fresh and I was got a few error on last step while install Ubuntu (because i have problem with my CDROM driver). Anyway, installation is continued .

For example when i tried to open ADDITIONAL DRIVER and LANGUAGE SUPPORT (on System Settings) nothing happened, it's not opening.

When i try this in terminal `gnome-language-selector` i'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-language-selector", line 8, in <module>
    from LanguageSelector.gtk.GtkLanguageSelector import GtkLanguageSelector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/LanguageSelector/gtk/GtkLanguageSelector.py", line 34, in <module>
    from aptdaemon.gtk3widgets import AptProgressDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/gtk3widgets.py", line 61, in <module>
    class AptStatusIcon(Gtk.Image):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/gtk3widgets.py", line 66, in AptStatusIcon
    def __init__(self, transaction=None, size=Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG):
AttributeError: type object 'GtkIconSize' has no attribute 'DIALOG'
```

Also getting this error for `jockey-gtk`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jockey-gtk", line 418, in <module>
    sys.exit(u.run())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jockey/ui.py", line 461, in run
    self.ui_show_main()
  File "/usr/bin/jockey-gtk", line 81, in ui_show_main
    col_icon.set_sizing(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.AUTOSIZE)
AttributeError: type object 'GtkTreeViewColumnSizing' has no attribute 'AUTOSIZE'
```

I'm worrying about are there any lack . I don't know what's wrong with my installation.

Are there any way, check my installation (packages, files etc..) .

Comment: Press Alt+F2, then type `gnome-terminal` and execute. Now in the gnome-terminal run: `sudo rm /var/crash/*` - this will clean all old crash reports. Now reboot and tell us if you still are getting this dialog.

Comment: @htorque , thank you. Now i'm not getting this error dialog . Now everything is OK with my installation ? For example when i tried to open ADDITIONAL DRIVER (on System Settings) nothing happened, it's not opening.

Comment: Can you open it now? Only time will tell if your system is okay. You just removed old crash reports that maybe got stuck somehow, but if there's still a problem you'll get that dialog again and you should just let it report the problem.

Comment: No, *additional driver* and *language support* isn't openning. When my first boot (after installation) i got a messege which said to me "language support isn't installed properly, do you want to download them now?" . And i hadn't internet connection because of this i clicked *later* button.

Comment: Can you again open a gnome-terminal and try to start `gnome-language-selector`? If it fails, please add the output to the question (you can just edit it instead of putting new info in the comments). Do the same for `jockey-gtk` (the *Additional Drivers* program).

Comment: @htorque thank you. You can check my question. I've edited it for you.

Comment: Related general question: [Getting “System program problem detected” pops up regularly after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with your system language (Turkish). See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/747796) for details.

Fortunately there has already been a fix released and pushed to the `natty-proposed` repository. This is the repository where all fixes for a stable Ubuntu release land for testing before they are moved to `natty-updates`.

It's not recommended to enable this (it's disabled by default so you don't end up with installing bad updates), so I suggest to just wait a couple of days for the fix to go into the `natty-updates` repository (which is already enabled on your system) and then do updates as normal.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm a Linux systems noob :) How can i reach to this updates ? I'm updating my system with `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: That way is fine, but it's not yet available. :) I talked to the developers and it's going to be available this week or early next week.

Comment: When it's available, will `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` solve my problem ?

Comment: Yes, this should fix the two programs (and probably others) not opening.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue and all I had to do was issue this command in terminal `sudo rm /var/crash/*` and it realy worked.

Comment: **Added detail needed:** This will remove any **old** crashes, that might still be reported (in error). After a reboot/re-starting, any further pop-ups still need to be investigated.

Comment: Also, be warned, that you should be **especially careful** when using `rm` with an asterisk. There is a huge difference between `rm /var/crash/*` and `rm /var/crash/ *`

Answer (score 2):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11218099

> `sudo sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/default/apport`

Comment: Is **apport** the cause, or a symptom?  Is harm caused if this is disabled?

Comment: Simply disabling apport doesn't solve the problem.