# Why should I trust the "System program problem detected" dialog?

Tags: security, password

This always shows up a few minutes after I log in:

[image: screenshot]

I have no idea what it is. If I click *Report problem*, it asks for my password:

[image: screenshot]

This is exactly what I would do if I wanted to steal someone's password.

Why should I trust it, and what is it going to do next if I comply?

Comment: possibly duplicate of : http://askubuntu.com/questions/43103/system-always-start-with-system-program-problem-detected-dialog

Comment: Good question, it can be abused for Social Engineering. Shouldn't the executed command be visible in that dialog?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: `gksu` has an option to replace the command with more user-friendly text, which is a clear social engineering risk.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that you're asking this because you're curious, not because you're really that worried about your password... it allows the bug reporting system `apport` reach your system logs to report a bug.

Comment: By default apport is turned OFF if you download the normal release and turned on if you use an RC, beta or earlier release.

Comment: Related on [security.se]: [Isn't the Ubuntu's system prompt for my password a bit unsafe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167412/isnt-the-ubuntus-system-prompt-for-my-password-a-bit-unsafe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're absolutely right, there is a possibility that this is some other software masquerading as Apport (the bug reporting software).

I wouldn't worry about it though, as this is the expected behaviour of Apport. If you have it enabled and a program crashes, a window similar to this will appear. Sometimes Apport needs to run as root to gather system information and send it to Launchpad.

If you don't want to run this risk, just disable Apport.

If you do decide to trust this prompt, you'll be able to inspect the report and find out which program is crashing on login.

To disable Apport:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type `gksu gedit /etc/default/apport` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Replace the line `enabled=1` with `enabled=0`.
4. Save and exit. You might have to reboot for the setting to come into effect.

Comment: Oh, this is Apport? I trust that program. I have now [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/794757) requesting that Apport identify itself before requesting privilege elevation.

Comment: funny thing is, I don't even have an apport process in the system monitor when this window pops up.

Comment: @Christoph: On my Ubuntu 17.04, while the password dialog is displayed `ps -e |grep apport` includes `/usr/bin/pkexec /usr/share/apport/apport-gtk`

Answer (score 2):

On terminal :

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

this will delete old *crash files*. And then restart your computer. If still you see this dialog
try these :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

(these are upgrade your packages with fresh ones) and restart.

Comment: Why are you telling me to delete my crash reports? This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Your are saying "i'm getting this error" . Maybe that happened after an installation / compilation process . If you can't solve your problem after reading crash reports you can delete them and then try again. Or basically, you can skip this step and update / upgrade directly :)

Comment: My "problem" is that I have no indication what this unsolicited password prompt is going to do. I have no reason to suspect that it is in any way related to my package manager.

Comment: Now that I know this prompt was generated by Apport, I'm sure glad I didn't delete my crash reports! That would have been exactly the *opposite* of what I want to do when a crash has been logged.