# How well is Ubuntu and Apport handling user's crash reporting process?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, apport

The `unattended-upgrade` exited with some error, and later in the Desktop session, I was asked to enter my password to be able to view some error occured which was a crash report for unattended-upgrade. Then I clicked the *continue* button of the crash reporting application (Apport right?) and the window closed )system-monitor showed a small upload) and that was that. I was asked to enter my password to view the problem, and when I did that and forwarded to the concerned, I didn't even get an acknowledgement?

[This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) mentions:

> If the user leaves the "Send error report" checkbox enabled, Apport uploads the collected information to the bug tracking system. After that it opens the packages' bug filing page with a sensible default bug title and leaves the rest of bug filing process to the web UI.

Is there a way to make apport acknowledge back together with the link to the bug report created? Mine was a duplicate to some previously reported bug, how's this handled?

Update 2.1: Now talking of one more crash (among many others, getting quite a few crashes!), this doesn't seem to be a duplicate and didn't show any uri to a previous bug report. With error reporting turned on again, it was probably sent. How am I to know about the progress?

**Also,** why apport used to ask for password even to view the crash report, but now it does not?

Update 2.2: Okay, just got this window:

[image: snap1]

Comment: look in `/var/crash` for old reports.

Comment: checking logs is not the question @wxl

Comment: oops read too fast. can't help you.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150194/should-i-be-asked-for-my-password-when-a-bug-report-is-sent and http://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie