# Report problem feature seems to be Broken on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: apport

Noticed the following on the desktop and the laptop at my home which both runs on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

As shown below, On the desktop first and later on the laptop after 
logging into the admin account after updating

[image]

Reporting is set to manual so after i click "Report problem..." it should ask for the password of admin account but it just goes away.

Why does this happen ? And there are .crash files at /var/crash/

Comment: @Terrance I'm not sure what the current intended behavior is, but the "System program problem detected" dialog box [at least *used* to prompt for a password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47675/why-should-i-trust-the-system-program-problem-detected-dialog).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie)   Error reporting does not require an account, but bug reporting does.