# I'm getting a lot of "System program problem detected" error dialogs, is there any way I can make them go away?

Tags: error-handling, apport

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 I get a lot of error messages with no info when the desktop starts:

[image]

How can I solve this? I tried to update and install kde-full and gnome. But it was not solved.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The following answer by rubo77 [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/369297/12540) fixed it for me:

Ubuntu has an error reporting system called [apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) which tries to catch all program crashes in the background and report them to help the developers.

It seems that after a dist-upgrade there are stuck some reports that are tried to resubmitted somehow, but disabling apport is not a desirable solution.

**Remove old crash-reports**

Remove all old crash-reports that might exist in the crash-report directory:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

After a reboot the popups are gone.

Any further new pop-ups still need to be investigated. If you want to see the details look in /var/crash/ for any new reports.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. This is a bug, right? The logs should be cleaned after reporting or after the upgrade.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too. I did a `cd /var/crash && ls` to check if there was anything there and indeed there was. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you be able to help point me in any direction to help understand how to read the crash reports from this app?