# Excessive amounts of errors Ubuntu 16.04 (Solved)

Tags: antivirus, bleachbit

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for about 9 months now. I have noticed an excessive amount of system errors and program errors pop up. Does this mean I have a virus? I use BleachBit to clean my system, I have no idea if this serves as an anti-virus and if it does can you link me a page explaining how to use it? I'm using Ubuntu Mate (I don't know if this matters.)

Comment: What are these errors you speak of? Please provide details.

Comment: I think [this is what you're talking about.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365358/im-getting-a-lot-of-system-program-problem-detected-error-dialogs-is-there-a)

Comment: @edwinksl There isn't really and specific errors that pop up just error reports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "System program problem detected" pops up regularly after upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade)

Comment: @Zacharee1 Never upgraded. I have always used Ubuntu 16.04 I'm still fairly new to using Linux.