# "System program problem detected" on login

Tags: 12.04

I changed from Window 7 because it has been hacked twice to Ubuntu and have been told that this program cannot been hacked.
After a sales person has installed Ubuntu I opened my computer for the first time and I got the message "System program problem detected". I wanted to report the problem but they asked me for a Password and I did not know the Password. So I carried on and it worked okay for me. Today - second day - again the same message than above "System..." the program has been hacked and someone has changed the writing - the letters are much smaller than before. 
My question is how can I solve the problem which has been detected? Can someone hack Ubuntu if it is not properly installed?

Answer (score 0):

"Hacked" is a very general term. Know that *any* system can be hacked. Linux software happens to have features that make it nearly impossible to hack in the same way you would a Windows system. Besides, since the majority of PC users use Windows, most viruses are made for Windows. However, viruses for Linux have been created - not successfully, and mostly for "experimentation" purposes, but it has been done.

I would very strongly recommend that you ask the people who installed Ubuntu on your computer for your password and change it as soon as possible. Usually, when installing new systems, it is common to have the password be the same as the username, so try that.

See this question about the errors: [Getting "System program problem detected" pops up regularly after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-dist-upgrade)

About the text size: it might be a good thing. Is it a problem? Your screen resolution may have been adjusted to be appropriate. Without more detail, it is difficult to tell what the problem is.