# Error pop ups appear everytime I log into Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system

Everytime I log into Ubuntu 14.04, I get a couple of error pop ups. Every single time.

[image]

It appears also sometimes a third on shortly after, for example after opening the browser.

How can I find out the reason for this pop-ups? and more importantly, how can I stop them?

**UPDATE:** Just to be clear, I do not want to "hide" message warnings. I want to find out the reason why this pop ups come, and how I could possibly fix them, as I am sure they are symptomatic of an underlying problem somewhere.

Comment: I dont want to "turn off" the message. They are symptomatic of a problem, I am sure. I want to repair that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was to delete all the files of crash reports with

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Apparently it was because there were some reports that were not being properly deleted automatically, and they were detected as new ones every time I rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

This question was handled well in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade). It shows how to clear the message log without disabling the error report system.

Comment: your link give me a Error 404

Comment: I'm sorry about that - I will check the text I typed.  Open a terminal window and type 'sudo rm /var/crash/*' without the quotes, of course.  This deleted the old crash logs which apparently sometimes get stuck in the machine.