# Ignore specific program's crashes in apport

Tags: crash, apport

If you have to use a program that crashes regularly some people tend to uninstall apport [(which you should not)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade/369297#369297).

So how could we exclude a program from apport's notifications?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`apport` has blacklist feature which I just noticed by `dpkg -L apport | grep etc`.

> ```
> # Blacklist for apport
> # If an executable path appears on any line in any file in
> # /etc/apport/blacklist.d/, apport will not generate a crash report
> # for it. Matches are exact only at the moment (no globbing etc.).
> ```

<sup>**source:** `/etc/apport/blacklist.d/README.blacklist`</sup>

There are already some examples in `/etc/apport/blacklist.d/` like `wine`, `firefox` & `thunderbird` because all have their own crash handler (direct upstream report).

1. So just create a new file in `/etc/apport/blacklist.d/`.
2. Put the absolute path of the executable in it.

Comment: I don't think wine is in there by default..

Comment: @ElderGeek, I wasn't precise about name. I meant `wine-preloader` declared in `/etc/apport/blacklist.d/apport`, Check `head /etc/apport/blacklist.d/*` .  The binary itself comes within `wine1.6-i386` package.