# System program problem detected showing at boot

Tags: boot

I have been facing this dialog for a long time lately. Though I've gone through multiple reinstalls of the system,the system program problem detected still keeps appearing after every boot. Plus after closing it, it opens one or two times again. It appears in both Ubuntu and lubuntu from 14.04. It occured on one more computer too but that might have been caused by the same ISO file (though it doesn't explain why it occurs in both lubuntu and Ubuntu cause thats different ISO file).
I tried to report the problem many times expecting that it would be fixed.
I searched for an answer Here on Ask Ubuntu but the only answer was to disable the crash reporter which is like taking painkillers and not even a word about how to FIX the problem. Same as our body hurts when it needs help, the system shows crash reporter in oder to be healed...

So now my question is:
What might be the cause of the problem and how to FIX it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 unity, 32 bit,the only system installed on the computer.

Comment: Have a look at this question, it looks like the same situation you're experiencing: [Getting "System Program Problem Detected" pops up regularly after upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the graphical frontend of apport. This could refer to a couple of problems, like program crashes, kernel oops, etc.
For more information you could read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport

The dialog always lets you view the source of the problem usually describing the problem, as well as seeing the affected program.
So really this is all of the help I can offer, because without providing any additional information it is not possible to help you.
Apport writes all its reports to `/var/crash`. You could zip that folder and upload it somewhere and I will have a look at it if you want, but keep in mind, the information contained in there could possibly risk your privacy, but most likely it wont.

If you want to disable apport (I do not recommend that) you can change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` in `/etc/default/apport`.