# Ubuntu 14.04 buggy

Tags: 14.04

Recently, I had to switch of my computer by pulling the plug. When I opened ubuntu, the following problems occur.

- constant blinking of the mouse
- font and the size(on-screen) of apps is randomly changing
- Input response is very slow.
- I can't shut down, i.e whenever I try to shut down, it goes to the logout page, and when I try to shut down *after that*, It asks 'Are you sure you want to shut down?' without giving an option for 'Yes' or 'No'.

The second time I booted Ubuntu, The error "System program problem detected" came up.

P.S I am a beginner with Ubuntu, so easy to follow responses are appreciated.I have a dual boot with Windows, which is not facing any problems

Comment: system problem detected is an automatic bug report, see here on how to fix that message http://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade

Comment: @mchid that is not the real problem. The problem is with the four aforementioned bugs.

Comment: i know, that wasn't answer, just a comment. Please open a terminal by pressing CTRL + ALT + T and then execute the following command: `lspci -v | grep "Kernel driver in use:"` this will provide us more info to get at the problem

Comment: please post the output of the command in your question so we can help, thanks!

Comment: You know that you can usually still (somewhat) safely reboot with the SysRq "magic keys" REISUB http://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop  Or here's how to enable them in case they're disabled http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124393/why-isnt-reisub-working-on-debian

Comment: @mchid, sorry for the late response.I am getting the following response-                                                          Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel                              Kernel driver in use: i915                                       Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel                             Kernel driver in use: pcieport Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd and so on – Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now you need to learn some command line fu, open up Terminal(usually shortcut is Atl+Ctrl+T).

Then if you'd like to learn what is eating your CPU simply type "top" and hit Enter. You could see what is loading you PC.

Then if you'd like to power you PC off, again type "sudo poweroff" in Terminal and hit Enter.

Everything else require at least looking into log files, you could check them through System Log application, Launch Unity then type system and you'll find a link to that app, click on it and you'll get access to some logs. Check for EE marks in X.org log.

Comment: Thanks! 'Top' reveals' the top two as hud-service and Xorg, any ideas?

Comment: ALso, there are noEE marks in Xorg log.

Comment: My guess would be something wrong with your video drivers and that could go anywhere from here, first if you could tell of what video card you have and what driver is in use "sudo lshw -c video" will give you some info. Also "lsmod" would list all kernel modules loaded. You would need to look for discrepancies between your card and drivers which are in use.