# "System problem detected" in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, bug-reporting, apport

When I start my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, the following dialog comes always. If I cancel it and restart, now also it simply comes again and I cannot stop it from coming.

[image]

My privacy setting as follows and my system is fully updated.

[image]

How can I get rid of this irritating issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try running `sudo rm /var/crash/*` in a terminal

[Answer source](https://askubuntu.com/a/369297/371765)

Answer (score 19):

If you really want to disable this alert/notification, you need to disable `apport` which is the crash reporting program of Ubuntu.

`apport` messages are generated from the logs in `/var/crash/`, so first try to remove all the files in that directory by `sudo rm /var/crash/*` and then reboot the computer.

If you want to disable these alerts permanently you need to disable `apport`. To do so, open the file by `sudo vim /etc/default/apport`, now change the line `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`.

Although disabling `apport` is not recommended.