# "System Program Problem Detected" at login

Tags: 14.04, authentication

I keep getting the system report of system programs: the action is `com.ubuntu.apport.apport-gtk-root`.

Why is this happening? Should I authenticate it?

I haven't allowed it since I'm not sure what it is and don't have a clue. I just click close and it doesn't come back; it only happens when I boot or reboot.

Comment: That message should not be regarded as a nuisance. It has some very important information. Please, give us more information. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What does the message in the window say? Can you give us a screenshot? Also, you should not be afraid to put your password into it. It is an application that came with Ubuntu, and is safe. There is almost no malware in the wild that affects GNU/Linux systems, so you do not need to be so cautious.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: I'm using 14.04 I can give you a screen shot in about 4-6 hours I can't go on my PC now sorry :P

Comment: It says 'cancel' or 'report' the error when I click 'report' it asks me to authenticate it. That's what happens then I just would close it since idk what it does.

Comment: @cat I would have posted it as an answer, but I feel that this problem isn't 'solved' until we can fix the messages. When you click 'Report', it asks you for your password because it is a bug reporting tool. Your password is needed to access some log files that help in the bug reporting process. Your password is not being sent anywhere. If you have any more information that can be of use to us, we'd appreciate it. We need to start narrowing down the problem and figure out what is crashing. Have you had any hardware problems or other issues with Ubuntu that could cause this?

Comment: No I don’t think so, my programs have been fine haven’t had a crash since I got Ubuntu 14.04 (yesterday :3). Although Minecraft (a game) has been freezing a lot when I jump from servers (joining one and leaving it and joining another) that’s all and when that happens I just restart my pc

Answer (score 0):

You probably have old crash logs that are sticking around. Try running

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

to delete the old reports.

[Getting "System program problem detected" pops up regularly after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade/369297#369297)