# How to investigate (or even fix) the odd blank area on my screen?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, desktop-background, nvidia-geforce

Everything works, but there is an anomaly which started a few weeks ago. An area which should display part of the wallpaper is all-white instead.

It is a small area, approx 0.25" tall and 3" wide, just below the header bar and just to the right of the Unity menu. 
It is only on monitor #1. It is only on workspace 1, not on the other 3 workspaces (ctrl-alt-right, it is not there). (I have 2x2 workspaces.)

If I click the background (the wallpaper image) the header bar displays "Ubuntu Desktop" at the left, but if I click the white area, those words disappear, as if it were a program with a GUI. There is no other response when I click or right-click that area.

If I use System Settings / Display and swap the monitors' positions, and click "Apply", everything redraws without the white area. Then if I revert to the original configuration, the white area remains gone!

So clearly, this isn't crucial, but maybe an investigation will be instructive.

I run dual monitors of different sizes with Unity under Ubuntu 14.04. (#1 is 1920x1080, #2 is 1600x1200). 
The PC is a Dell Optiplex 755. 
lspci shows the graphics card is "NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310] (rev a2)". 
I have not installed graphics drivers other than the default. 
(This setup is affected by the UI freeze that can be avoided by de-selecting "Transparency" in the view options in LibreOffice.)

Comment: When you take a normal screenshot (PrintScreen key or running `gnome-screenshot`), is the white area present there as well? If yes, please upload the screenshot (you can upload it to https://imgur.com and share the link here).

Comment: Please open a terminal, run the command `xprop WM_CLASS` - your mouse cursor will turn into a cross-hair (+), click on the white area with it. Then [edit] your question to add the terminal output. In case it looks like `WM_CLASS:  not found.`, repeat the procedure but with the command `xprop` only. Thanks.

Comment: @Byte  Thank you! The screenshot by Kazam shows a problem in displaying on two different-sized-monitors. The white area is the bottom of a System Program Problem Detected dialog box, which also displays offscreen above the desktop!.  (The error itself is a vestige of a long-ago error, displayed due to the  recurring-problem-report problem, which is solved elsewhere here.) Shots at http://imgur.com/a/77uaQ .

Comment: @Byte Unsure if I should delete this question, or, how I can mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a screenshot of your entire desktop (using `gnome-screenshot` or the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key).

This is the image you just uploaded:
[image: your screenshot]

As you can see, there's a dialog window sitting in the top left desktop corner, so that most of it are outside your visible area.

You can move the window back into the visible area by holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then dragging the window using the mouse while holding the left mouse button. By holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, it is irrelevant on which part of the window you click, you can grab it anywhere, not only at the title bar.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out the dialog box was an instance of the "repeatedly reporting the same problem after reboot" problem, which is also handled on askubuntu: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade)