# Disable "System program problem detected" for segfaults in my own programs

Tags: apport, segmentation-fault, signal

I don't mind being notified about *system* programs that SEGV -- I would actually like to report those cases, so this is not a duplicate of [Getting “System program problem detected” pops up regularly after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/133385/455520).

However, I spend quite a lot of time writing bad C code and I get segfaults from my own userspace programs quite often, and I'd like to stop seeing "System program problem detected" for my own, non-system applications.

Is this possible, or does Apport just watch `init`'s children for `SIGSEGV` and pop up on any segfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed this was fixed since I asked this question on Ubuntu 16.10. Userspace programs that weren't installed from a package and don't have a signed `.desktop` file associated with them no longer issue a dialogue like this.

This answer can't really apply to older versions of Ubuntu, though I would still be interested to know the answer for older versions.