# Stop the "System program problem detected." pop-up without disabling error reporting

Tags: 18.04, crash, bug-reporting, debug

everytime I login on my computer, a pop-up appear containing:

> System program problem detected.

And no further informations, I mean I don't have any clues on what's wrong I can just report it or close the pop-up.

So I looked in [various forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade) and found that

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Could be a solution, **but** I have 2 problems:

1. When I type this I have the following output:

> rm: cannot remove '/var/crash/*': No such file or directory

2. I don't want to disable error reporting within Ubuntu, I just want it to precisely tell me what's wrong and not just display me an annoying pop-up without any informations.

Comment: what do the logfiles say,please copy and paste the part of your logfile into the question.

Comment: Where can I find the information you are looking for ?

Comment: you go to programs-tools there you will find the logs.