# System problem detected

Tags: boot, system

Recently, after booting the window appears "System Problem Detected" - and I choose "Report problem". So how can I find out what actually is the problem? Otherwise everything works as expected. Xubuntu 18.04 on HP15 laptop.

Comment: I have the same on 19.04 Budgie. Started  today for me. So it might be a bug. The popup does not help... no details or anything to go on

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/133385/getting-system-program-problem-detected-pops-up-regularly-after-upgrade

Comment: Check for a .crash file in /var/crash

Comment: OK, with the /var/crash file I know what may have caused it. I'm aware of the situation (dkms, non-kernel WiiFi module) and have a workaround. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "System Problem Detected" popup usually means that a crash occured.

The *apport* application listens for crashes. When one occurs, it constructs a .crash file in /var/crash with plenty of details for bug triagers to understand how and why the crash occurred.

Look in /var/crash for the .crash file to learn the cause. It's an ordinary text file - you can open it in any text editor.

Comment: with sudo privilege.

Comment: @Janos Hmmm. I find that I don't need to use sudo: `gedit /var/crash/filename.crash` opens the file in gedit properly in a stock 19.04 test system. Opens properly in Nautilus, too.

Comment: U're probably right, I've already removed the file, but I remember that Thunar had a tiny "x" on the file icon, so I did sudo cat linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic.0.crash | less - sorry, I could not make the formatting, tried ctr+k or sp sp sp sp

Comment: A simple `less /var/crash/filename.crash` should suffice for most folks. It should be user-readable. The developers *want* you to be able to read it. You can also pastebin the file for convenient browsing from a desktop.