# System program problem detected

Tags: login

This question of mine is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43103/system-always-start-with-system-program-problem-detected-dialog).

Unlike the problems faced by the user who asked that question.. I am not facing any problems anywhere. Infact my installation process was flaw-less unlike the one in the question.

**It's just that whenever i login for the first time after a reboot, i get the same dialog-box as in that question.**
 There are infact even more similar questions on the main site but none of the answers addressed that how to reach the the problem causing area and analyse it so that it could be repaired then on.

I want to know that what's causing that error message which shows up only when i log it after a reboot (not with subsequent logout-login)

Additional info : its a ubuntu minimal install - added LAMP & Mail server stack via tasksel - cinnamon as GUI - MDM as LoginManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning the old error logs... just remove all the files from the folder containing the error logs.. A couple of times its a possibility that the system will show us the error messages from the old logs still living in the cache...

I guess the location is 
sudo rm /var/crash/*

Comment: this just cleared the error logs, i know. The popup never bothered me again. BUT I STILL CANNOT FIND OUT WHAT THE PROBLEM WAS DUE TO ?

Comment: @Z9iT Please don;t use caps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem which was really discouraging because error messages are one of the reasons I run away from Windows. Anyhow, I searched around and couldn't find the problem so I just silenced it. I edited this file as root

> /etc/default/apport

and changed the line that says

> enabled=1

to

> enabled=0

That's it. I have had no error messages ever since.

Comment: I don't want to disable the notifications for such problems... i want to go to the root cause of the problem ans solve it there !